# Azure Emulator won't start, web role unhealthy

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-emulator

I've got problems running the Azure Emulator, the web role gets Unhealthy status.

The problems started today after a Windows Update installed several new updates. Yesterday all worked fine.

I've tried to create a new empty Cloud Service project in Visual Studio 2015 with Azure SDK 2.7. The emulator startup dialog loads to 3/4 of the progress bar and when I look into the Compute Emulator the Web role is stated as Unhealthy.

After a while Visual Studio hangs and I have to kill the process.

I've tried the following

- Updating Visual Studio
- Reinstalled Azure SDK 2.7
- Uninstalled all previous versions of the SDK
- Restarted the computer several times

No luck whatsoever. I'm running out of ideas and would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by repairing the Visual Studio installation. Works fine now.

Comment: really?!? what was broken? did you do a complete reinstall?

Comment: I just repaired Visual Studio from Add/Remove programs in Control Panel. This solved my issues.

Comment: Just FYI: I have a similar issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926079/role-in-azure-compute-emulator-stuck-cycling-between-unknown-and-destroyed-state) but repairing VS 2015 didn't help.